# How to set soap headers in zeep when header has multiple elements

Tags: python, wsdl, soap-client, soapheader, zeep

I am trying to use python zeep to connect to a soap service ( using wsdl ).

Following is the soap-ui generated XML for an operation.

However I am finding it **difficult to identify how to set soap headers**. 
In this case, we have ***multiple XML elements within the header***.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:acm="http://www.acme.com/ACM">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <acm:MessageID>?</acm:MessageID>
          <acm:ExName>?</acm:ExName>
          <acm:Authentication>
             <acm:Username>?</acm:Username>
             <acm:Password>?</acm:Password>
          </acm:Authentication>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <acm:LIST_STOCKS>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <acm:STOCKID>?</acm:STOCKID>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <acm:PRODUCT>?</acm:PRODUCT>
          </acm:LIST_STOCKS>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I'll leave an answer here for future reference.

It is not that clear from the documentation, but you can just set the elements by setting `_soap_headers` with a dictionary.

In the given example:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:acm="http://www.acme.com/ACM">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <acm:MessageID>?</acm:MessageID>
          <acm:ExName>?</acm:ExName>
          <acm:Authentication>
             <acm:Username>?</acm:Username>
             <acm:Password>?</acm:Password>
          </acm:Authentication>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <acm:LIST_STOCKS>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <acm:STOCKID>?</acm:STOCKID>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <acm:PRODUCT>?</acm:PRODUCT>
          </acm:LIST_STOCKS>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

You would send the headers like this:

```py
# Prepare header values and dicts
MessageID = 000
ExName = 'Value'
Authentication = {'Username': 'User', 'Password': 'YourPassword'}

# Set required body content
LIST_STOCKS = [] 

# Call service and set SOAP headers directly in _soapheaders using dictionary
response = 
self.client.service.WebServiceName(_soapheaders={'MessageID': MessageID, 'ExName': ExName, 'Authentication': Authentication},LIST_STOCKS=LIST_STOCKS)
```

Comment: Posted a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201921/how-to-set-soapheaders-in-zeep-using-dictionaries) if you are interested.

Comment: ...now with a bounty.